# "where" clause in template helper

Tags: templates, meteor, collections, schema, where-clause

First of all Hello to all,

I am new to Meteor and just a hobby developper. Something I am sure pretty simple has been bugging me for the last days and I will try to explain my issue through a simple example.

Lets consider an online forum where I have Categories of Forums and in each of them one of more forums.

I would like the final result in my template to be something like:

```
{{#each category}}
  {{#each forum where forum.category=category}}
    {{nameForum}}
  {{/each}}
{{each}}
```

and that would list the category and for each of them the different forum inside of it.

My questions are:
would be what's the best approach for such a problem ? meaning:
Shall forums be a sub-elements of the categories in the Schema but then the shcema seems a bit complicated.
Shall forum and categories be separated schema but in the same collection but then how can I do this "where" in the template ?
Do I have a totally silly approach on the issue and I missed something in the tutorial ?

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Ivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this

myTemplate.html

```
{{#each getCategories}}
  {{#each getForum categoryName}}  // Assuming that in your category db you have categoryName field
    {{nameForum}}
  {{/each}}
{{each}}
```

myTemplate.js

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    getCategories: function() {
        return Category.find({});
    },
    getForum: function(category) {
        return Forum.find({"category": category});
    }
})
```

Basically you move the logic of retrieving the forum inside your template helper

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I think is missing in your reply is that I still have to specify the "sport" category in the template. Ideally I would like it to automatically loop through all the categories. Would something like this work : (I can't try it now from where I am): {{#each getForum category.name }} ?